# invalid initialization of reference of type 'delai_assemblage*&' from expression of type 'delai_assemblage'

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

hi every body i have a problem in language C and i can't fix it here is my code :

```
void demande_usine_stockage(entrepot *u_s,fournisseur f[],int *demande,delai_appro &d_a,delai_ass &d_ass,usine_ass *u_a,int *attente_stockage,int *attente_assemblage,int *debut_stockage,int *fin_stockage,int *debut_assemblage,int *fin_assemblage,int periode)
{
 u_a->commande_en_souffrance += *demande;
 u_a->niveau_stock=u_a->stock_physique - u_a->commande_en_souffrance;
if (u_a->niveau_stock >= *demande)
 {
       *debut_stockage=periode;
       *fin_stockage=periode+u_a->L_assemblage;
       stockage(u_s,demande,d_a,u_a,debut_stockage,fin_stockage,attente_stockage,periode);
 }
 else
 {
     *debut_stockage=periode+f[1].L;
     *fin_stockage=(periode+u_a->L_assemblage+f[1].L);
     stockage(u_s,demande,d_a,u_a,debut_stockage,fin_stockage,attente_stockage,periode);
     demande_usine_assemblage(f,u_a,d_ass,demande,attente_assemblage,debut_assemblage,fin_assemblage,periode);
 }
}
```

and délai_ass is a linked list
here is the error

`430 G:\test1.cpp invalid initialization of reference of type 'delai_assemblage*&' from expression of type 'delai_assemblage'`

Comment: Have you **read** the error message?

Comment: Looks like C++. Please retag.

Comment: (Also, who uses non-English identifiers? I mean, I love French because it's a nice language, but please...)

Comment: no it's C and not C++

Comment: Please update the language tag. You also need to say which line is line 430. Not clear how this is C as you claim, seeing as the file name is test1.cpp and the error message is a C++ error.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really C, not C++, then rename your file to have a `.c` extension, not `.cpp`.  C and C++ are two different languages, and you should not be compiling `.cpp` files as C code.

You'll also need to remove all reference types (types with a `&` in them, before the identifier), since C does not have references.  For example:

```
void demande_usine_stockage(
    entrepot *u_s,
    fournisseur f[],
    int *demande,
    delai_appro *d_a,  // Reference (&) changed to pointer (*)
    delai_ass *d_ass,  // Reference (&) changed to pointer (*)
    usine_ass *u_a,
    int *attente_stockage,
    int *attente_assemblage,
    int *debut_stockage,
    int *fin_stockage,
    int *debut_assemblage,
    int *fin_assemblage,
    int periode)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i forgot to tell you i use this 
'typedef struct delai_livraison *delai_livr;typedef struct delai_assemblage *delai_ass;'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a variable of type `delai_assemblage` where a pointer to `delai_assemblage` is expected. I would guess that you are passing such variable as the `d_ass` parameter where you are calling your `demande_usine_stockage` function.